# Copy constructor chosen over move constructor when returning non-static local object

Tags: c++, vector, g++, move-semantics

I used to assume that a class' move constructors would be given priority over its copy constructors, but in the code below it seems that the copy constructor is chosen even though the object should be movable.

Do you have any idea why below codes choose copy constructor when `foo()` returns `vector<B> B`?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class B {
public:
  int var_;

  B(int var) : var_(var)
  {
    cout << "I'm normal" << endl;
  }

  B(const B& other)
  {
    cout << "I'm copy constructor" << endl;
  }

  B(B&& other)
  {
    cout << "I'm move constructor" << endl;
  }
};

vector<B> foo()
{
  vector<B> b;

  b.push_back(1);
  b.push_back(2);

  return b;
}

int main()
{
  vector<B> b {foo()};
}
```

The result is as shown below.

```sh
$ g++ main.cpp
$ a.out
I'm normal
I'm move constructor
I'm normal
I'm move constructor
I'm copy constructor
```

Curiously, if I remove one line in `foo()`, the move constructor is chosen instead:

```cpp
vector<B> foo()
{
  vector<B> b;

  b.push_back(1);

  return b;
}
```

Now the result is like below:

```sh
$ g++ main.cpp
$ a.out
I'm normal
I'm move constructor
```

Comment: When the vector is moved, its elements are completely unaffected.

Comment: The second `push_back` causes the vector to be resized and reallocated; then the existing data is copied from the old to the new. Add `b.reserve(3);` in your `main` and you won't see the copy.

Comment: The vector copies its content to expand when you insert (it has nothing to do with returning). It does so because your move constructor is potentially throwing. So it isn't safe for it to do moves. Declare `B(B&& other) noexcept`

Comment: If you print something before `return b;`, you will notice that all the moving and copying has completed before the vector is returned.

Comment: thank you everyone, I learned much!

Answer (score 3):

There are two things involved: vector reallocation and selection of mechanism when reallocating.

First, reallocation occurs here:

```
vector<B> foo()
{
  vector<B> b;

  b.push_back(1);
  std::cout << "Vector capacity: " << b.capacity() << " Vector size: " << b.size() << "\n";
  b.push_back(2); //capacity() == size(), reallocation is needed

  return b;
}
```

Most vector implementations make capacity `2*current_capacity` when `current_capacity` would be exceeded, to conform to amortized-constant complexity required by standard.

---

Now, compiler can only choose move constructor for reallocation if it is marked as `noexcept`. In order to make vector use move constructor, declare it like this:

```
B(B&& other) noexcept
{
//
}
```

---

You can remove the reallocation altogether by reserving space upfront:

```
vector<B> foo()
{
  vector<B> b;
  b.reserve(2);
  b.push_back(1);
  b.push_back(2);

  return b;
}
```

Or by initializing vector in one go:

```
vector<B> foo()
{
  return vector<B>{1, 2};
}
```

Comment: thank you so much ^^ , so far my understanding is that RVO for vector is not the problem here, the logs that I've seen and confused are originated by mis-implementation of class B and mis-using it in foo() , if I'm wrong please let me know